# Find and remove all directories with multiple names?

Tags: linux, unix

```
find ./myfolder -type d -name example -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Removes every directory called example.

But how would I get something like this to work?

```
find ./myfolder -type d -name example -o -name docs -exec rm -rf {} +
```

To remove all example AND docs directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add explicit grouping:

```
find ./myfolder -type d \( -name example -o -name docs \) -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This is required because `find`, like in programming and math in general, interprets `-o` with lower precedence than the implicit `-a` you have otherwise. Your original query was interpretted as:

```
find (dirs, those named "example") OR (files named "docs", and delete them)
```

---

PS: For your future convenience, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically warns many things like this:

```
In yourscript line 1:
find ./myfolder -type d -name example -o -name docs -exec rm -rf {} +
                                                    ^-- SC2146: This action ignores everything before the -o. Use \( \) to group.
```

Comment: Turns out it needed the -type in there and the single quotes: \( -type d  -name 'example' -o -name 'docs' \), but thanks! I didn't know about shellcheck!

Comment: @TidusSmith The single quotes are not required in this case (but may be if you use different names in your actual code). If you put the `-type d` inside the parens, it will only apply to "examples", and the command will go on to delete regular files named "docs"

Comment: Yes, you're right about the -type d and quotes. I misinterpreted an error. Thank you.